# maximum memory for batch jobs with qsub

Tags: out-of-memory, cluster-computing, dynamic-memory-allocation, qsub

At my working environment we have a cluster with some 33 physical nodes. Each node has 2 virtual machines (VMs) with 10 CPUs (4 slots) and 112Gb memory each.

I am submitting jobs to this cluster and below is the maximum memory that the jobs required (obtained with `qacct -j [job]`

```
maxvmem      37.893GB
maxvmem      37.660GB
maxvmem      37.980GB
maxvmem      41.059GB
maxvmem      41.615GB
maxvmem      38.744GB
maxvmem      38.615GB
```

Let's consider the maximum required memory to be 42GB for the rest of this question.

In fact, when submitting 92 jobs to this cluster (without specifying any qsub paramter), I noticed that some of them crashed, apparently due to memory issues. All the jobs that crashed where running on physical nodes with four jobs. Which makes sense: if I have four jobs running on a physical node with 42GB each, 4*42 = 168 (>112), so I am not surprised that some jobs crashed.

I then decided to limit the memory per job. According to [this link](https://bioinformatics.mdc-berlin.de/intro2UnixandSGE/sun_grid_engine_for_beginners/how_to_submit_a_job_using_qsub.html), this can be done via the `-l h_vmem=[maxmem]` qsub parameter, which was added to the shell script submitted to the queue (below I am showing the first three lines of the .sh script, whereas the second line is the one that should be limiting the memory). Note that `-l h_vmem` is the memory per slot

```
#! /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=28G
echo HOSTNAME: `hostname`
```

After submitting the 92 jobs, if I do `qstat -j [job]` I see a line such as:

```
hard resource_list:         h_vmem=28G
```

Which means 28*4 = 112GB per physical node, which is my limit. That looks OK

However, I see that some physical nodes have already 4 jobs running in it, which is what I wanted to avoid. Given that each job can take up to 42GB of memory, I would expect to have a maximum of 2 jobs per physical node (maximum memory required would be 2*42 = 84GB), so that they would not crash due to lack of memory.

So it seems that qsub is not interpreting correctly the paramter `#$ -l h_vmem=28G` on my .sh script as the required memory can go up to 42x4 = 168GB, whereas 28x4 = 112GB should be my limit.

Am I using the wrong qsub parameter (`-l h_vmem`), the wrong notation on my .sh script (`#$ -l h_vmem=28G` - probably not, as this appears to have been correctly parsed, when issuing `qstat`), or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The option `-l m_mem_free=42G` would help in this situation. The amount of memory is per slot.
From the documentation: If a host can’t fulfill the `m_mem_free` request then the host is skipped.
[2021.1 documentation](https://2021.help.altair.com/2021.1/AltairGridEngine/8.7.0/UsersGuideGE.pdf)